# OnBind() called too early

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

I have a problem that when activity call `startService()` and follow by `bindService()` in cause NPE @ `onBind()` in my service class because my Thread might be not finish initialize yet. In this scenario how can I guarantee that `locationThreandMessenger` is ready before `onBind()` trigger .

**xxx Service Class**

```
public class xxx extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "xxx";
    private Messenger locationThreadMessenger;
    private LocationThread locationThread;

    private void onWorkPrepared() {
        locationThreadMessenger = new Messenger(locationThread.mHandler);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return locationThreadMessenger.getBinder();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        isNewThreadNecessary();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void isNewThreadNecessary() {
        if (locationThread != null) {
            if (locationThread.isAlive()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Thread is alive...");
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "Thread was reused...");
                locationThread.start();
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Initializing new Thread...");
            locationThread = new LocationThread("Thread");
            locationThread.start();
        }
    }

    private class LocationThread extends HandlerThread {

        private static final String TAG = "Thread";

        private Handler mHandler;

        public LocationThread(String name) {
            super(name);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onLooperPrepared() {
            super.onLooperPrepared();
            mHandler = new Handler(getLooper()) {
                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

                }
            };
            onWorkPrepared();
            Log.i(TAG, "Thread started...");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are using a `HandlerThread` in a wrong way, you dont need to extend it at all

Comment: why it is a wrong way? please advice.

Comment: just do: ht = new HandlerThread("bla bla bla"); ht.start(); h = new Handler(ht.getLooper()) {...

Comment: how about my other implementation inside the class?

Comment: I have many logic about location inside this class actually.

Comment: what logic do you mean? what do you need `HandlerThread` for?

Comment: ahh.. mean code that handle everythings about get location or listenning to location update.

Comment: and why a HandlerThread ?

Comment: I want to seperate this service from MainThread

Comment: so do it the way i presented above

Comment: thank you for you advice I will try, and how about the down side of what I done? can you describe for me?

Comment: you are not using `getLooper()` that's why your Thread is not synced with a main UI Thread

Comment: ?? I did in onLopperPrepareed()

Comment: onLopperPrepareed is called not in the main Thread

Comment: and why it should have to synced with a main UI Thread ?

Comment: `"In this scenario how can I guarantee that locationThreandMessenger is ready before onBind() trigger"` that's why

Comment: because I don't want my service crash effect with UI Thread

Comment: I see so you prefer to let it in main thread.

Comment: crash I mean somethings that can block UI Thread

Comment: it will not block UI Thread, why would it?

Comment: because you said in sync with UI Thread and looper is from UI Thread?

Comment: just try `new Handler(ht.getLooper())` in the main UI Thread and see what happens

Comment: okay, and how you going to guarantee with it? use synchronized{} ??

Comment: I will try it first..

Comment: **public Looper getLooper()** "This method returns the Looper associated with this thread. If this thread not been started or for any reason is isAlive() returns false, this method will return null. If this thread has been started, this method **will block** until the looper has been initialized."

Comment: yes it work, so HandlerThread associate with MainThread now() anythings which take a long operation in HandlerThread will bloc UI am I right ?

Comment: nothing will block UI, `HandlerThread` is a `Thread` so everything is done in the background

Comment: Thank for your help, do you have any good document about thread but thank you so much any way

Comment: "good document about thread"? what you mean?

Comment: ahh.. I want to now more about Thread, HandlerThread, UI Thread in android that what I mean.

Comment: just ask uncle google for: "Thread, HandlerThread, UI Thread" it will answer with namy links including that for example: http://blog.nikitaog.me/2014/10/11/android-looper-handler-handlerthread-i/

Comment: Thank @pskink you did save my date really !

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this would be a good practice or not (I'm sure in not). but for now this is my fix. It work without freeze an UI

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    while (locationThreadMessenger == null) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return locationThreadMessenger.getBinder();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try `wait()` and `notify()` but if your `onLooperPrepared()` took a while then you could get `ANR` since service run on the main thread.

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    if (locationThreadMessenger == null) {
    synchronized (locationThread)
    {
         locationThread.wait();
    } 
    }
    return locationThreadMessenger.getBinder();
}

private class LocationThread extends HandlerThread {

    private static final String TAG = "Thread";

    private Handler mHandler;

    public LocationThread(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "run");
        Looper.prepare();
        synchronized (this)
        {
            mHandler = new Handler() {
                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

                }
            };
            onWorkPrepared();
            Log.i(TAG, "run after onWorkPrepared");
            notify();
        }
        Looper.loop();

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try? The onBind method wait for the LocationThread to call notify()  before it continue on to the return statement.

Comment: Your app still crash?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83270/discussion-between-hoan-nguyen-and-jongz-puangput).